# Add value to the key in the list PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable which ask to add new name which will be add to the list. But it's not working if the list has `{}` except of this `[]`. To `[]` i can't add a value, because it gives me an error.
I want to add value and key to the list, from the variables.

```
users={"Peter": 600, "Georgo": 700, "Mike": 800}

def add_user():
    new=str(input("Zadaj meno nového zamestnanca: "))
    users.append(new)
    print(users)
```

Comment: `users` is a dictionary. Each key has to have a value, so "appending" a single string to a dictionary makes no sense. What do you want that string to correspond to?

Comment: `append` is for lists, not dictionaries

Comment: See here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a dictionary, you cannot `append` to it, but you can do the following:

```
users={"Peter": 600, "Georgo": 700, "Mike": 800}

def add_user():
     new_user=str(input("Zadaj meno nového zamestnanca: "))
     new_number=str(input("input a number:"))

     users[new_user] = new_number

     print(users)
```